# How to get all data from firebase real-time database into an 3d array

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to pull all data on my firebase real time database to a 3d array.
I achieved the above using snapshot.forEach and I want to iterate through the array to use all of its data in my DOM javascript.

my 3d array is an array containg arrays of objects.
for exp. let test = array[0][3].playerName

If i tried to call the above, it says can't access property 0, fullList[0] is undefined
and certainly, when I try to call fullList in console, it is undefined but the console.log() after calling the function works and returns the 3d array.

```
            function findPlayers() {
                for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    let hostInfo = findList(i);
                    const dbReference = ref(db, hostInfo);

                    onValue(dbReference, (snapshot) => {
                        let ara = [];
                        // pushes each object into ara and pushes ara to a global empty list.
                        snapshot.forEach(function (childsnapshot){
                            let item = childsnapshot.val();
                            item.key = childsnapshot.key;
                            ara.push(item);
                        });
                        fullList.push(ara);
                    });
                }
            }

const fullList = [];
findPlayers();
console.log(fullList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that data is loaded from Firebase (and most modern cloud APIs) asynchronously, and won't yet be available when your `console.log(fullList);` runs.

It's easiest to see this by adding some logging:

```
console.log('before calling onValue');
onValue(dbReference, (snapshot) => {
  console.log('got data');
});
console.log('after calling onValue');
```

When you run this, the output you get is:

> before calling onValue
> after calling onValue
> got data

This is probably not the order that you expected, but it is the normal order when calling an asynchronous API. And it perfectly explains why your `console.log(fullList)` doesn't show any data: as the data hasn't loaded yet.

---

There are a few solutions for this.

The simplest one that always works is to move any code that needs the data into the `onValue` callback:

```
function findPlayers() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let hostInfo = findList(i);
        const dbReference = ref(db, hostInfo);

        onValue(dbReference, (snapshot) => {
            const fullList = [];
            let ara = [];
            // pushes each object into ara and pushes ara to a global empty list.
            snapshot.forEach(function (childsnapshot){
                let item = childsnapshot.val();
                item.key = childsnapshot.key;
                ara.push(item);
            });
            fullList.push(ara);
            console.log(fullList);
        });
    }
}

findPlayers();
```

Now your `console.log(fullList)` will only run one all data is loaded.

---

An alternative is to pass in a callback function to `findPlayers`, that you then call when the data has been loaded. This is similar to what `onValue` itself does, and allows you to separate the code that uses the data from the code that loads it.

```
function findPlayers(callback) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let hostInfo = findList(i);
        const dbReference = ref(db, hostInfo);

        onValue(dbReference, (snapshot) => {
            const fullList = [];
            let ara = [];
            // pushes each object into ara and pushes ara to a global empty list.
            snapshot.forEach(function (childsnapshot){
                let item = childsnapshot.val();
                item.key = childsnapshot.key;
                ara.push(item);
            });
            fullList.push(ara);
            if (i == 4) callback(fullList); 
        });
    }
}

findPlayers((fullList) => {
  console.log(fullList);
});
```

---

A third and nowadays most common alternative is to get `get()` instead of `onValue` and use the promise that returns to switch to `async`/`await`.

```
async function findPlayers(callback) {
    const fullList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let hostInfo = findList(i);
        const dbReference = ref(db, hostInfo);

        const snapshot = await get(dbReference);
        let ara = [];
        // pushes each object into ara and pushes ara to a global empty list.
        snapshot.forEach(function (childsnapshot){
            let item = childsnapshot.val();
            item.key = childsnapshot.key;
            ara.push(item);
        });
        fullList.push(ara);
    }
    return fullList
}

findPlayers().then((fullList) => {
  console.log(fullList);
});
```

---

Also see:

- the MDN documentation on [asynchronous programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing)

Answer (score 0):

You can return a Promise from the findPlayers function and use async/await to wait for it to resolve before accessing fullList.
Example:

```
async function findPlayers() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let hostInfo = findList(i);
    const dbReference = ref(db, hostInfo);
    let ara = [];

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      onValue(dbReference, (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childsnapshot) {
          let item = childsnapshot.val();
          item.key = childsnapshot.key;
          ara.push(item);
        });
        fullList.push(ara);
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
}

const fullList = [];
findPlayers().then(() => {
  console.log(fullList);
});
```